# Handling factors using data.table R package

Tags: r, data.table, factors

How can I add labels at the factor below using data.table code instead? 
Basically, I wanted to run the exact code (from base R) below using the R package 'data.table' this time.

```
data$vrb <- factor(data$vrb, levels=c(0,1,2,4,6), labels=c("x0","x1","x2","x4","x6"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
data[ , vrb := factor(vrb, level=c(0,1,2,4,6), labels=c("x0","x1","x2","x4","x6"))]
```

Although you could check to see if this is sufficient:

```
data[ , vrb := as.factor(vrb)]
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks!